# ASP.NET application impersonate user with netonly to access network share

Tags: iis-7.5, asp.net, network-share, web.config, impersonation

We have an ASP.NET application running on Server A which is on its own domain, in the web.config we are impersonating a user.  Now this application needs to access a folder on Server B which is on a different domain, and Server B declines the access due to lack of privilege.

So we manually tried from cmd to impersonate the same user with "/netonly" and it then was able to access the Server B folder.

Now how do we achieve this programmatically?  Any help would be really appreciate it!